# Bayesian inference of a coin's bias when we don't directly observe the flips

Tags: bayesian, inference, markov-chain-montecarlo

Consider a coin with bias $p$. We generate a random sample $x_1, \dots, x_n \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$, but **we do not observe results of these coin tosses**. Instead, for each $x_i$, we observe a set of features $y_{i1}, \dots, y_{im}$ about the flip, e.g. the height of the toss, the coin's rotational velocity, etc.

Then we feed the observed feature vector $\mathbf{y}_i$ into a black box predictor (perhaps a logistic regression or tree-based model trained on past observations). The model yields $\hat{p}(\mathbf{y}_i) \in [0,1]$, which we interpret as the probability that $x_i = 1$.

I am trying to figure out how to use $\hat{p}(\mathbf{y}_1), \dots, \hat{p}(\mathbf{y}_n)$ to obtain a posterior distribution on $p$. My initial idea is to run the model $\hat{p}$ on a test dataset, and obtain the empirical distributions $P(\hat{p} \mid x = 0)$ and $P(\hat{p} \mid x = 1)$. We then have all the likelihood functions for the hierarchical model (ignoring the $\mathbf{y}_i$'s) and can generate MCMC samples of $p$.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Is there a better way? Can we gain anything by making assumptions about the model $\hat{p}$?

Comment: Please clarify: You first say that the $x$ values are not observed, but later you say that you are thinking of running a model on a test data set where you condition on values of $x$.  You need to be clear on *what information you actually have* --- i.e., what is observed, and what is not.

Comment: Indeed, to build a predictor you do require a learning sample made of $({\mathbf y}_i,x_i)$ pairs. From there, once the function $\hat{p}(.)$ is constructed, this behaves like a particular statistic and a posterior conditional on that statistic is just a generic posterior.

Comment: You're right, I should have mentioned that the training and test datasets consist of instances where the result of the flip $x_i$ is observed.